# How to find $a_n$ series from Dirichlet generating function

Tags: generating-functions, project-euler

I am solving problems from Project Euler. Solutions for some of the problems is $n^{\rm th}$ term of a series. I know *Dirichlet generating functions*. How to find $n^{\rm th}$ term of a series from Dirichlet generating function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula :

---

Let $a(n)$ be an arithmetic function, and let

$$g(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a(n)}{n^{s}}$$

be the corresponding Dirichlet series. Presume the Dirichlet series to be uniformly convergent for $\Re(s)>\sigma$. Then Perron's formula is

$$ A(x) = {\sum_{n\le x}}' a(n)
=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} g(z)\frac{x^{z}}{z}  dz.\; $$

Here, the prime on the summation indicates that the last term of the sum must be  multiplied by 1/2 when $x$ is an integer. The integral is not a convergent Lebesgue integral; it is understood as the Cauchy principal value. The formula requires $c > 0, c > \sigma,$ and $x > 0$ real, but otherwise arbitrary.

---

Then $a(n) = A(n + \varepsilon) - A(n-\varepsilon)$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will try your answer to solve some problems.

Comment: This is what you would do if you were given a function $g(s)$ and knew nothing about it.  If you're using Dirichlet generating functions to solve combinatorial problems like those on the Euler project, then you will usually already know, for instance, $a(n)$ and $b(n)$ and you need to compute the $n$th term of the convolution $(a\ast b)(n).$  That is much easier to compute: it's just
$$(a\ast b)(n) = \sum_{d|n} a(d)b(n/d).$$

Comment: If this was what you were looking for, please mark it as the accepted answer.